# Is it good practice to having route.navigate statement in child component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to redirect from child component to another component. Is it a safe practice or side effects will occur.

Comment: I agree on downvoting without commenting, that's really a bad practice. Btw, if you are using a smart/dumb components structure, dumb components shouldn't have side effects. But navigation is usually stateless, so you won't have any negative impact. But think on re-usability, are you sure that you can re-use a component that performs a redirect in a certain url?

Comment: Thank you so much. I think  that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of the architecture that you chose.

If you want reusable component for :

- Your application
- An Another application
- Or to create a web component

Then you have to keep all actions in your parent (@Output/@Input) and not in the children.

**But** if you are confident that it will not be reusable, then there is no problem to have `this.router.navigate()` inside the children.